# Travis: Is there a way to use env vars to install package versions programmatically on container-based infrastructure?

Tags: travis-ci

In the `.travis.yml` for one of my projects, I determine what packages to install based on environment variables that I also set in the `.travis.yml` file.  It looks like this:

```
env:
 - CABALVER=1.18 GHCVER=7.8.1
 - CABALVER=1.18 GHCVER=7.8.2
 ...

before_install:
...
 - travis_retry sudo apt-get install cabal-install-$CABALVER ghc-$GHCVER
...
```

That's under the legacy infrastructure.  I would like to [switch to the container-based infrastructure](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/), which would mean replacing the `before_install` line with something like:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
    - cabal-install-$CABALVER
    - ghc-$GHCVER
```

...except that won't work, because env vars aren't set until after Travis attempts to install the requested apt packages. So, if I try to use the above, I get an error about how I'm trying to install packages called `cabal-install-` and `ghc-` (with the ending hyphens, but minus the version suffixes), which of course don't exist.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want on the container-based infrastructure?  I could try to install all the versions at once and use the env vars later to determine which one to use on a given job, but (even if I could prevent all hell from breaking loose as a result of having multiple GHCs and Cabals installed at once) it would be really slow to install all of them for every build job, and that would negate the purpose of switching to container-based infrastructure.

Comment: Would specifying multiple `apt` keys in a [build matrix](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Build-Matrix) work? I'm not sure if this applies to your specific case, but it might help.

Comment: Hm.  The docs say that the build matrix tests combinations of "Runtime", "Environment", and "Exclusions/Inclusions".  I don't think there's a way to specify which packages I want from apt as part of that.  Although I realize now that -- unlike in the past, when only 7.4 was supported -- Travis will now let you specify different GHC versions: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/haskell/#Specifying-the-GHC-version.  I'm not sure if it supports all the versions I want, though...

Comment: Hm, I always  thought that any keys can be stuffed into the build matrix and it Just Works. ICBW though.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!  Sad to see I'll have to switch to the legacy infrastructure to pull it off, but it that's what it takes, it's better than nothing.

Comment: @couchand If you specifically need multiple versions of GHC, you may want to look at how it is done here: https://github.com/hvr/multi-ghc-travis -- that's what mine is based on.  But, yes, to do that you have to use the legacy infrastructure, and judging by the lack of answers to this question, there may not be a way around that.

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to test against multiple versions of LLVM.  Thanks, though!